# Cannot convert from stringw to string / char

Tags: c++, string, c++11, irrlicht

I have been trying to convert from a `irr::stringw` (irrlicht game engine core string) so that I can simply explode the string at a delimiter to create an array / list.

However, I cannot convert from stringw, which is not compatible with any normal functions.

So, to split the `stringw` into a list I have the following:

```
vector<stringw> split(stringw str, char delimiter){
    vector<stringw> internal;
    std::string tok;
    std::string std_s(str.c_str(), str.size());

    while (getline(std_s, tok, delimiter)) {
        internal.push_back(tok);
    }
    return internal;
}
```

However errors here are: `str.c_str()` says `No instance of constructor "std::basic::string matches argument list. Argument types are (const wchar_t*, irr:u32)`

On the `getline` method the error: `No instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (std::string, std::string, char).`

I have been trying for hours a number of ways to just split a `stringw` at a delimiter of ";" (semi colon) but nothing is working. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues here, the first is that `stringw` is a string of `wchar_t` characters. So we need to use the `std::wstring` [facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide) to avoid having to convert `wchar_t` to/from `char`.

We also need to note that `std::getline` requires a type derived from [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) as it's first argument. We can therefore modify your code as follows:

```
vector<stringw> split( stringw str, wchar_t delimiter )
{
    vector<stringw> internal;
    std::wstring tok;
    std::wistringstream std_s( str.c_str() );

    while( getline(std_s, tok, delimiter) ) {
        internal.push_back(tok);
    }
    return internal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`?

```
vector<stringw> split(stringw str, wchar_t delimiter)
{
    vector<stringw> internal;
    std::wstring tok;
    std::wistringstream std_s(str.c_str());

    while (getline(std_s, tok, delimiter)) {
        internal.push_back(stringw(tok));
    }
    return internal;
}
```

Edit: you might need to use the stringw constructor, maybe like this:
`stringw(tok)`